# Core Image filter intermittently crashes when running in a NSOperation

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation, core-image, metal

I have a simple `Core Image` filter running in a `NSOperation`. It works most of the time, but, every now and then it will crash (*the rest of the code never crashes that doesn't use Core Image*). When it crashes, it always has the same backtrace pointing to `MetalTools-[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder setSamplerState:atIndex:]`.

Normally I only run the filter once per image, but if I put the filter in a for loop and run it 50 times per image, it will crash usually between the 10th and 20th image it has processed in the `NSOperationQueue`. But running it repeatedly makes it so the crash is reproducible for the most part.

Here is my Core Image filter:

```
func adjustImage(withSaturation saturation: Float, image: UIImage!) -> UIImage? {

    let ciimage = CIImage.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)

    if self.isCancelled {return nil}

    let filter = CIFilter.init(name: "CIColorControls")
    filter?.setValue(ciimage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(saturation, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)

    if self.isCancelled {return nil}

    let result = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage

    if self.isCancelled {return nil}

    let context = CIContext.init(options: nil)

    if self.isCancelled {return nil}

    //When it crashes, it always crashes on the following line:
    if let cgimage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent) {

        if self.isCancelled {return nil}

        let image = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgimage)

        if self.isCancelled {return nil}

        return image
    }

    return nil
}
```

When it crashes, it always crashes on the same line that calls `context.createCGImage()`

Are `Core Image` filters not thread safe? That is what it seems.

Here is the backtrace:

```
* thread #22, queue = 'Render Style All Queue (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x79315beb8)
    frame #0: 0x00000001819e4430 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
    frame #1: 0x00000001a61fc2d8 MetalTools`-[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder setSamplerState:atIndex:] + 436
    frame #2: 0x00000001878aa824 CoreImage`CIMetalRenderToTextures + 512
    frame #3: 0x000000018790ee30 CoreImage`CI::MetalContext::compute_quad(CGSize const&, void const**, unsigned long) + 320
    frame #4: 0x000000018790f414 CoreImage`CI::MetalContext::render_node(CI::TileTask*, CI::ProgramNode*, CGRect const&, CGRect const&, void const**, unsigned long) + 508
    frame #5: 0x000000018790fa28 CoreImage`CI::MetalContext::render_root_node(CI::TileTask*, CI::ProgramNode*, CGRect const&, void () block_pointer) + 192
    frame #6: 0x00000001877c9fb8 CoreImage`CI::Context::recursive_render(CI::TileTask*, CI::Node*, CGRect const&, CI::Node*) + 904
    frame #7: 0x00000001877ca564 CoreImage`CI::Context::render(CI::ProgramNode*, CGRect const&) + 116
    frame #8: 0x00000001877f78ec CoreImage`CI::create_cgimage(CI::Context*, CI::Image*, CGRect, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat, bool, unsigned long) + 2408
    frame #9: 0x000000018778963c CoreImage`-[CIContext(Internal) _createCGImage:fromRect:format:colorSpace:deferred:textureLimit:] + 1088
    frame #10: 0x00000001877882bc CoreImage`-[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:] + 196
  * frame #11: 0x0000000102f0777c MyApp`TDTMyStyle.adjustImage(saturation=1.10000002, image=0x00000001c02aad40, self=0x00000001c42e5400) at TDTMyStyle.swift:944
    frame #12: 0x0000000102f058c0 MyApp`TDTMyStyle.comp(imageForComp=0x00000001c40bd5e0, scaledStyleImage=0x00000001c02aad40, modelNumber=57, self=0x00000001c42e5400) at TDTMyStyle.swift:811
    frame #13: 0x0000000102f02e00 MyApp`closure #2 in TDTMyStyle.main(self=0x00000001c42e5400, medianCorrectionDiameter=0x000000016d7ae268) at TDTMyStyle.swift:315
    frame #14: 0x0000000102f01ed4 MyApp`thunk for @callee_owned () -> (@error @owned Error) at TDTMyStyle.swift:0
    frame #15: 0x0000000102f03f9c MyApp`thunk for @callee_owned () -> (@error @owned Error)partial apply at TDTMyStyle.swift:0
    frame #16: 0x00000001055d4e1c libswiftObjectiveC.dylib`ObjectiveC.autoreleasepool<A>(invoking: () throws -> A) throws -> A + 68
    frame #17: 0x0000000102efd83c MyApp`TDTMyStyle.main(self=0x00000001c42e5400) at TDTMyStyle.swift:339
    frame #18: 0x0000000102f040fc MyApp`@objc TDTMyStyle.main() at TDTMyStyle.swift:0
    frame #19: 0x0000000102f9a7bc MyApp`TDTMyAppMyStylePreview.main(self=0x00000001c42e5400) at TDTMyAppMyStylePreview.swift:371
    frame #20: 0x0000000102f9aa64 MyApp`@objc TDTMyAppMyStylePreview.main() at TDTMyAppMyStylePreview.swift:0
    frame #21: 0x000000018307d620 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
    frame #22: 0x000000018314f004 Foundation`__NSOQSchedule_f + 404
    frame #23: 0x000000010572545c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #24: 0x0000000105732800 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_continuation_pop + 592
    frame #25: 0x000000010573109c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 628
    frame #26: 0x0000000105736b54 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 616
    frame #27: 0x0000000105736880 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 136
    frame #28: 0x00000001823ab120 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1268
    frame #29: 0x00000001823aac20 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: don't suppose you have a runnable version?

Comment: I don't, but I can make one tomorrow and update my post then.

Comment: As the backtrace indicated a debug symbol, I tried running my target in release mode and the issue does not occur. So since it is not really a critical issue, I am just going to move on.

Comment: We don’t know why it happened but it probably won’t happen again :)

Comment: Well at least it won't happen for the release build which is what is important. ;)

Comment: Exactly, there's absolutely no reason to believe there will be problems in the release build. ;)

Comment: exactly the same issue. When I use CIContext with rendering on CPU the code works.